# Visual Studio 2015 - ASP.NET - Dapper - Can't see exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I'm writing a small ASP.Net application, and one of the things that it needs to do is get data from a SQL Server database by calling a stored procedure. I've chosen to use Dapper as I've used it before (in non-ASP.NET code) with good results. Because I'm only ever calling stored procedures, I've written a small wrapper around the Dapper call:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this IDbConnection connection, string storedProcedureName,
        object storedProcedureParameters = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
{
    var command = new CommandDefinition(storedProcedureName, storedProcedureParameters, transaction, commandTimeout, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var result = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(command);

    return result;
}
```

Problem is that when I start my site and the above code gets called, something is going wrong on the line where it actually makes the `QueryAsync` call. When I debug, trying to run that line just causes the debugger to stop working and return to my browser, with the page not loaded.

If I wrap the `QueryAsync` call in a try..catch block, and set a breakpoint in the catch block, the breakpoint is never hit. In Visual Studio I have unchecked the 'Just my code' debug option, but that didn't make a difference.

Why can I not see what's going wrong in the `QueryAsync` call?

Comment: Is anything being send to the server? (Use the SQL Profiler) Have you  you tried to wait for the result instead of returning async? (Bad practice but might help you in finding the issue)

Comment: Yes I've used the profiler and I can see that the procedure is being executed (with no errors). I'm more interested in finding out why the debugger isn't breaking on an exception. If I could see the exception I would have a pretty good chance of working out the issue!

Comment: I've managed to fix my issue - I've switched to using AsyncController, so now call the database lookup with and await statement, instead of looking at the Result object. However that doesn't really answer my question about why Visual Studio wasn't breaking on the actual exception.